# Add value to hidden field Magento 2 admin

Tags: magento2, addfield

I am trying to add a hidden field with a value to my Magento 2 admin form.

I used the following code:

```
$fieldset->addField('order_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'order_id', 'value' => 'Test']);
```

However, the code does not set a value. Anybody any idea how to set a value to a hidden field?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use code below to set value for specific hidden field

```
$form->setValues('your_hidden_field_name', $value);
```

your case can be **`$form->setValues('order_id', $orderId);`**

Answer (score 0):

**Try to set field value like below**

```
$field = $fieldset->addField('order_id', 'hidden', ['name' => 'order_id', 'value' => 'Test']);
$field->setValue('Test');
```